# How to link a database table to itself and get the query results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need your help in getting the data from a table called "Earnings" and to link it to itself twice. The "Earnings" table has the columns:

```
PaymentDate   EmployeeID   Description   Amount

30-Jun-2016   111          Basic         100

30-Jun-2016   111          Telephone     20

31-May-2016   111          Basic         100

31-May-2016   111          Telephone     10

31-May-2016   222          Basic         200
```

I got a requirement to prepare a query to calculate the differences of the employees payments between the selected month "Jun-2016" and the previous month and I should add 3 more columns (Current Month Payment - Last Month Payment - Difference).

If the payments are the same with the previous month, I shouldn't show them. But, if the payment is exist in the previous month and it is not available in this month or null for this month, I should show its value for the previous month and for the current month I should show it as zero.

I only started to initiate the query and then I need your help to continue:

```
select e.paymentdate, e.employeeid,e.Description,e.amount
from earnings e, earnings x
where e.employeeid = x.employeeid
```

3 fields need to be added currentmonthpayment - previousmonthpayment - difference (current-previous)

Comment: Step 1 - replace `*` with just the fields you need from the applicable alias (e and x).

Comment: @DanBracuk I have added the fields from the table, but I am not sure on how to display the amounts under the correct columns which I will add them (Current month - Previous Month - Difference)

Comment: I suggest you go to office hours (or whatever the equivalent may be at your school) and get help from your teacher. SO is not the place to learn how to include desired column names in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below SQL to get the desired data

```
    select e.employeeid, current_month_earning, prev_month_earning, (current_month_earning - prev_month_earning ) as difference
from 
(
    select 
        employeeid
        , sum(amount) as current_month_earning
    from 
        earnings
    where 
        to_char(paymentdate,'YYYYMM') = to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')
    group by 
        employeeid
) current_month_earnings
(
    select 
        employeeid
        , sum(amount) as prev_month_earning
    from 
        earnings
    where 
        to_char(paymentdate,'YYYYMM') = to_char(trunc(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'YYYYMM')
    group by 
        employeeid
) prev_month_earnings
where current_month_earnings.employeeid = prev_month_earnings.employeeid
```